# how to setup breakpoint in gdb with shared library function

Tags: gdb

I have problem with gdb, it wasn't stop in one function. Can you explain why and how to stop program after calling strcpy?

```
grzes@trampek:~/poligon$ gdb ./char_array2 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/grzes/poligon/char_array2...done.
(gdb) list
1    #include <stdio.h>
2    #include <string.h>
3    
4    int main() {
5       char str_a[20];
6       printf("ssss");
7       strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
8       printf(str_a); 
9    }
10    
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048465: file char_array2.c, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/grzes/poligon/char_array2 

Breakpoint 1, main () at char_array2.c:4
4    int main() {
(gdb) break strcpy
Breakpoint 2 at 0x1a1205
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
ssssHello, world!

Program exited with code 016.
(gdb) q
grzes@trampek:~/poligon$
```

Answer (score 7):

You may be using gcc's `__builtin_strcpy`. Compile with `gcc -fno-builtin` and see if that helps.

For more info see: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options

Comment: yes, it helps - compiler changes strcpy into memcpy for optimization purpose using gcc's switches -fno-builtin prevents from such behave

Comment: @user480162: gcc will automatically use `__builtin_strcpy` in certain cases rather than calling the standard library `strcpy` unless you compile with `-fno-builtin`. Use `gcc -S` to see what's being generated in your case.